# Git LFS: Smudge error: Error downloading jar : LFS: Client error

Tags: git, git-lfs

I am having some trouble using **git lfs** to pull down code from git origin. We have git-lfs integrated into our repository, and when we issue a **git pull** command, git-lfs is used to pull down jar files that we have in our repository source control. I am now trying to pull down a branch, which has jar changes in it, and I am receiving the error below:

```
Error downloading object: ourRepo/ourRepo/Jars/ourJar.jar (8b200ef): Smudge error: Error downloading ourRepo/ourRepo/Jars/ourJar.jar (8b200efda95c6d6f2672dc23b5aae0abb9e60b303705c9f65b785ef9d80691d1): LFS: Client error: https://api.media.atlassian.com/file/2897df4a-ce54-4e69-9817-910758ed6355/binary
```

Has anyone encountered this issue, and what was the solution?

Comment: I have found [this link](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1720) to be useful. Specifically, running the `git lfs install --skip-smudge` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ultimately found my answer from this github issues link:
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1720

My specific situation was trying to switch to a different branch with `git checkout`, which would then automatically try to do a `git pull` on the branch, and fail to pull since there was an issue upstream with a java jarfile committed with `git-lfs`.

The final solution was to run `git lfs install --skip-smudge` then do `git checkout`. Note that after running with the `--skip-smudge` flag, you'll have to manually `git lfs pull` to get the latest jar files.